# Python xlsxwriter formula result referenced in a separate Excel Workbook

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Apologies for the simple question, I'm guessing there is probably an obvious answer to this question that I have missed.

What I am trying to do is reference the result of a formula from a separate Excel file.  So I have a script creating an excel for each file (group of log files) generating various stats.  Meanwhile I have a 'Main' file created earlier in the script which just collects key summary data from each individual file in parallel.

My script below is calculating an answer using a formula (formula47) and writing to its individual Excel file (worksheetFILTER_ON), but I also what to post the answer to my Main Excel workbook (worksheetMAINAv), but as the output is representing a reference to a different workbook I get #REF! printed. Any ideas on how to get around this?

```
cell_range = xl_range(0, col47+3, tot47, col47+3)
formula47 = '=AVERAGE(DATA!%s)' % cell_range
worksheetFILTER_ON.write('O2', formula47 ,bold)

worksheetMAINAv.write(9, MAINcolno, formula47, bold)
```

Thanks,
MikG

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code you've shown. Perhaps you could replace it with a small but complete working example that shows the issue.

Comment: Thanks jmcnamara for you feedback.  I decided my discription was a bit unclear, so i posted an updated question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114594/python-with-xlsxwriter-to-save-or-assign-formula-result-as-a-value-for-use-later