# Python with Xlsxwriter to save or assign formula result as a value for use later on

Tags: python

I'll be honest and say that I asked a similar question the other day, but I think I over complicated the question and so it wasn't particularly clear on what I a looking for.

To sum up my previous question, whilst using xlsxwriter I am looking for a way of storing/assigning the result of a formula as a numerical value so that I can reference it later on in the script and so avoiding a recalculation. I should mention that I am producing two separate Excel files in the process, so want to avoid the dreaded #REF! error on the second Excel workbook

Apologies for the crude code, but something like below is kind of what I am looking for, but 'result' would have been assigned a number like '12.56' for example, so when I write to a second Excel workbook I avoid the recalculation and simply input the assigned value of 'result'

```
# on first EXCEL workbook calculate result and store as number
cell_range = xl_range(0, col+3, tot, col+3)
formula = '=AVERAGE(DATA!%s)' % cell_range
worksheetFILTER_ON.write('O2', formula ,bold)

result = formula 

# on second EXCEL workbook print numerical result
worksheetMAIN.write('A1', result ,bold)
```

I hope this makes a bit more sense than my last attempt.

Thanks,
MikG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update is a little bit clearer but the question is still missing the part that would help someone answer this: a small working example.

One thing to note is that XlsxWriter doesn't calculated the result of a formula. The `result` variable in the code above is just a reference to `formula` variable which is a string like `'=AVERAGE(DATA!A1:D4)'`.

If you are using that formula in a worksheet that doesn't have a worksheet named `DATA` then you will probably get the `#REf` error that you were referring to.

Comment: Thanks jmcnamara for reading this problem.  My code works fine in theory, so this is a working example, but what I am trying to collect is the formula result rather than the formula =AVERAGE(DATA!A1:D4).  So I can avoid #REF! in the second Excel.  Is there some way of running the formula and capturing the resulting answer, and then assign this answer to another variable (like 'result')?  As you say the #REF! error will appear as the cell links to another worksheet, so I am hoping to avoid any linked Excels, and just capture the formula result.

Comment: By *working example* I meant a complete working example, not pieces of code that are working. It is easier to answer code than text.

Comment: *Q: Is there some way of running the formula and capturing the resulting answer*. A. No. XlsxWriter doesn't calculate the result of a formula.